# Adding two values from two different activities through Shared Preferences

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

i am making an application which has one Main Activity and 11 other Activities , each activity of these 11 has to return a value and the Main Activity is supposed to add these values together and display the total on a Text View , at the beginning it was just giving me the total of the last Activity i have been to , so i tried to send values through Shared Preferences and add them together in the Main Activity

This is the code of my main activity :

```
package cafe.al_sheikhabuhamzehcafe;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ItemMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

Button cDrinks;
Button hDrinks;
Button sandwiches;
Button snacks;
Button meat;
Button chickenarrayes;
Button water;
Button snooker;
Button billiards;
Button qallayat;
Button hookah;
TextView total;

public static  String BToatal = "BilliardsTotal";
public static  String STotal = "SnookerTotal";
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_menu);

    cDrinks             =       (  Button  )   findViewById        (  R.id.              cDrinks  )         ;
    hDrinks             =       (  Button  )   findViewById        (  R.id.              hDrinks  )         ;
    sandwiches          =       (  Button  )   findViewById        (  R.id.           sandwiches  )         ;
    snacks              =       (  Button  )   findViewById        (  R.id.               snacks  )         ;
    meat                =       (  Button  )   findViewById        (  R.id.                 meat  )         ;
    chickenarrayes      =       (  Button  )   findViewById        (  R.id.       chickenarrayes  )         ;
    water               =       (  Button  )   findViewById        (  R.id.                water  )         ;
    snooker             =       (  Button  )   findViewById        (  R.id.              snooker  )         ;
    billiards           =       (  Button  )   findViewById        (  R.id.            billiards  )         ;
    qallayat            =       (  Button  )   findViewById        (  R.id.             qallayat  )         ;
    hookah              =       (  Button  )   findViewById        (  R.id.               hookah  )         ;
    total               =       ( TextView )   findViewById        (  R.id.                total  )         ;

    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);


}



public void cDrinks (View v)
{
    Intent cd= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ColdDrinks.class);

    startActivity(cd);
}

public void hDrinks (View v)
{

    Intent hd = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HotDrinks.class);

    startActivity(hd);

}

public void qallayat (View v)
{

    Intent q = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Qallayat.class);

    startActivity(q);

}

public void sandwiches (View v)
{

    Intent sand = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Sandwiches.class);

    startActivity(sand);

}

public void snacks (View v)
{

    Intent snack = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Snacks.class);

    startActivity(snack);

}

public void meat (View v)
{

    Intent sawanee = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SawaneeMeat.class);

    startActivity(sawanee);

}

public void chickenarr (View v)
{

    Intent chicken = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Chicken.class);

    startActivity(chicken);

}

public void water (View v)
{

    Intent water = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ColdWater.class);

    startActivity(water);

}

public void hookah (View v)
{

    Intent hookah = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Hookahs.class);

    startActivity(hookah);

}

public void billiards (View v)
{

    Intent billiards = new Intent(this,Billiards.class);

    startActivityForResult(billiards,9710);

}



public void snooker (View v)
{

    Intent snooker = new Intent(this,Snooker.class);

    startActivityForResult(snooker,9711);



}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode==9710) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String billiardstot = data.getStringExtra("btot");

            BToatal = String.valueOf(billiardstot);

            String bt = String.valueOf(billiardstot);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

            editor.putString(billiardstot, bt);

            editor.commit();


        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Request Code", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    if (requestCode==9711) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            String snookertot = data.getStringExtra("stot");

            STotal = String.valueOf(snookertot);

            String st = String.valueOf(snookertot);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

            editor.putString(snookertot, st);

            editor.commit();


        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Result Code", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}


public void totcalc (View v)
{


    sharedpreferences.getString(BToatal,null);
    sharedpreferences.getString(STotal,null);


    Intent gettot = getIntent();

    Double imfromcd = gettot.getDoubleExtra("cdtot",0 )  ;
    Double imfromhd = gettot.getDoubleExtra("hdtot",0 )  ;
    Double imfromq  = gettot.getDoubleExtra("qtot", 0 )  ;
    Double imfromsand = gettot.getDoubleExtra("sandtot",0);
    Double imfromsnack = gettot.getDoubleExtra("snacktot",0);
    Double imfromsawanee = gettot.getDoubleExtra("sawaneetot",0);
    Double imfromchicken = gettot.getDoubleExtra("chtot",0);
    Double imfromcw = gettot.getDoubleExtra("cwtot",0);
    Double imfromh = gettot.getDoubleExtra("htot",0);



    String gtotal = String.valueOf(STotal) + String.valueOf(BToatal) + imfromcd + imfromhd + imfromq + imfromsand + imfromsnack + imfromsawanee + imfromchicken + imfromcw + imfromh;

    total.setText(String.valueOf(gtotal));

}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
}
```

i'v only done Billiards and Snooker Activities so far..

so , this is the code of Billiards Activity :

```
package cafe.al_sheikhabuhamzehcafe;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

public class Billiards extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText ebgames;
Button   bsave;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_billiards);

    ebgames = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ebgames);
    bsave   = ( Button )findViewById(R.id.  bsave);


}

public void bsave (View v)
{

    Double dbgames = Double.parseDouble(ebgames.getText().toString());
    Double calcbgames = (dbgames)*0.50;

    Double btotal = (calcbgames);


    Intent billiards=new Intent();
    billiards.putExtra("btot",String.valueOf(btotal));
    setResult(9710,billiards);
    finish();


}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    Double dbgames = Double.parseDouble(ebgames.getText().toString());
    Double calcbgames = (dbgames)*0.50;

    Double btotal = (calcbgames);


    Intent billiards=new Intent();
    billiards.putExtra("btot",String.valueOf(btotal));
    setResult(9710,billiards);
    finish();


    super.onBackPressed();
}
}
```

and this is the code of Snooker Activity :

```
package cafe.al_sheikhabuhamzehcafe;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Snooker extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText esgames;
Button   ssave;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_snooker);

    esgames = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.esgames);
    ssave   = ( Button )findViewById(R.id.  ssave);



}

public void ssave (View v)
{

    Double dsgames = Double.parseDouble(esgames.getText().toString());
    Double calcsgames = (dsgames)*1.00;

    Double stotal = (calcsgames);


    Intent snooker=new Intent();
    snooker.putExtra("stot",String.valueOf(stotal));
    setResult(9711,snooker);
    finish();


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    Double dsgames = Double.parseDouble(esgames.getText().toString());
    Double calcsgames = (dsgames)*1.00;

    Double stotal = (calcsgames);


    Intent snooker=new Intent();
    snooker.putExtra("stot",String.valueOf(stotal));
    setResult(9711,snooker);
    finish();


    super.onBackPressed();

}
}
```

the problem is when i press the button that's supposed to calculate the total from every Activity it shows "BilliardsTotalSnookerTotal (and the rest of the totals from other Activities)" , i don't know how to get the correct value or total to the Main Activity

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: create a public class file use two methods get and set sharepreference data. send your value to setsharepreference method , get previous sharedprefece value first add it with the new value and update the sharedPreference

Answer (score 0):

1) Your **BToatal** and **STotal** are acting as **keys**, so no need to assign the value to it in onActivityResult.

2)  In totcalc (View v) method, you will try to get the values against theses **keys**. 
Values are of **String type**, so if you directly perform the add operation on String, it will **concatenate** the String. Instead *convert theses Strings into double* and then perform addition.
Since setText(CharSequence text) method of TextView takes String, finally convert **totalValue** to string.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode==9710) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String billiardstot = data.getStringExtra("btot");
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(BToatal, billiardstot);
            editor.commit();

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Request Code", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    if (requestCode==9711) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String snookertot = data.getStringExtra("stot");
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(STotal, snookertot);
            editor.commit();

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Result Code", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}


public void totcalc (View v)
{
    String billiardstotTotal = sharedpreferences.getString(BToatal,null);
    String snookerTotal = sharedpreferences.getString(STotal,null);

    Intent gettot = getIntent();

    Double imfromcd = gettot.getDoubleExtra("cdtot",0 )  ;
    Double imfromhd = gettot.getDoubleExtra("hdtot",0 )  ;
    Double imfromq  = gettot.getDoubleExtra("qtot", 0 )  ;
    Double imfromsand = gettot.getDoubleExtra("sandtot",0);
    Double imfromsnack = gettot.getDoubleExtra("snacktot",0);
    Double imfromsawanee = gettot.getDoubleExtra("sawaneetot",0);
    Double imfromchicken = gettot.getDoubleExtra("chtot",0);
    Double imfromcw = gettot.getDoubleExtra("cwtot",0);
    Double imfromh = gettot.getDoubleExtra("htot",0);

    Double totalValue = imfromcd + imfromhd + imfromq + imfromsand + imfromsnack + imfromsawanee + imfromchicken + imfromcw + imfromh
    totalValue += Double.valueOf(billiardstotTotal) + Double.valueOf(snookerTotal);
    total.setText(String.valueOf(totalValue));
}
```

Comment: it kinda worked , now it adds the total of activities other than (Billiards,Snooker) to the total of them , but the total of the two activities never changes to anything other than "7.5" it only changes when i add something else from any different screen , should i do that on the rest of the activities? , please help me , i must finish it today

Comment: first check the values of these variables(billiardstot , snookertot), by putting log in OnActivityResult method . Are you getting the correct value ?

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like this in your main activity

```
public void billiards (View v)
{
    Intent billiards = new Intent(this,Billiards.class);
    startActivity(billiards);
}

public void snooker (View v)
{
    Intent snooker = new Intent(this,Snooker.class);
    startActivity(snooker);
}

public void totcalc (View v)
{
    double billiardsTotal = sharedpreferences.getFloat(BToatal,0);
    double snookerTotal = sharedpreferences.getFloat(STotal,0);

    double totalFromActivities = billiardsTotal + snookerTotal;

    total.setText(String.valueOf(totalFromActivities));

}
```

Then in your other activities do this

```
public class Billiards extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText ebgames;
Button   bsave;
public static  String BToatal = "BilliardsTotal";
Double dbgames = 0;
Double calcbgames = 0;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_billiards);
    ebgames = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ebgames);
    bsave   = ( Button )findViewById(R.id.  bsave);
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
}

public void bsave (View v)
{
    dbgames = Double.parseDouble(ebgames.getText().toString());
    calcbgames = (dbgames)*0.50;

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putFloat(BToatal,calcbgames);
    editor.apply();

    finish();
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    dbgames = Double.parseDouble(ebgames.getText().toString());
    calcbgames = (dbgames)*0.50;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putFloat(BToatal,calcbgames);
    editor.apply();

    finish();

    super.onBackPressed();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Handling ***SharedPreferences*** are very easy!

**Activity one, two, three:**

Here you create the data and save in shared preference.
While saving, you can use **predefined ID/name of that screen** to identify from where the value is coming. **Repeat the code in every activity** and use the appropriate ID while storing value.

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("YourSharedPreference", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
int VALUE_TO_PASS = <your value here>;
editor.putInt("ACTIVITY_ONE", VALUE_TO_PASS); //ACTIVITY_TWO,ACTIVITY_THREE...
editor.commit();
// Now screen shift
```

**MainActivity**
Here you will retrieve the values one-by-one, using the SAME id you have used to save the values

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("YourSharedPreference", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
int DEFAULT_FALLBACK_VALUE = 0;  //When value is not received, show this
int VALUE_PASSED_ACTIVITY_1 = sp.getInt("ACTIVITY_ONE", DEFAULT_FALLBACK_VALUE);
int VALUE_PASSED_ACTIVITY_2 = sp.getInt("ACTIVITY_TWO", DEFAULT_FALLBACK_VALUE);
int VALUE_PASSED_ACTIVITY_3 = sp.getInt("ACTIVITY_THREE", DEFAULT_FALLBACK_VALUE);

int Total = VALUE_PASSED_ACTIVITY_1 + VALUE_PASSED_ACTIVITY_2 + ...;
```

Saving these IDs in a **constant class, or in static final array** will be better than hard-coding them.